Regex for matching a certain number of words
I have the following string pattern, from which I'm trying to grab the first 4 to 5 words after the first occurrence of -:
OBJ: redacted - We can't save this record: because the “FBE Record-Trigger: redacted After Save” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the “FBE Account To Oppty Partner AE” process failed. Give your admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW: unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 32 records: 0068z0000025NS1AAM,006t0000003YfgFAAS,006t00000046pFEAAY,0068z0000027ULKAA2,0068z000002YmpsAAC,006t00000046p7bAAA,006t00000046p7OAAQ,0068z0000026AgJAAU,0068z0000029VutAAE,006t00000046p7LAAQ, ... (22 more).
In the above string, I'm trying to match the following text: We can't save this record:
I tried the following regex: -\s+\b(\w+)\b, which only captures the first word: we. I tried to quantify the captured group pattern using {5} with a back reference and without, still no luck. Also, I don't really need to capture, I just need to match the first n number of words after -.

Are you trying to match the literal text We can't save this record or are you trying to match some limited amount of whatever text appears after the dash?

@StephenP, matching some limited amount of whatever text

This example is 5 words, will the text you want always be 5 words? Will you always match up until finding the word "because"? How will you know how many words to match since you don't already know the text? You need to be able to express a condition that ends the match, like n words, or until x.  — Separately: your pattern \b(\w+)\b when applying {4} to it doesn't account for the spaces between words. \b is a word boundary, it acts more like a lookahead in that it finds the non-word character but doesn't consume it.

/-((\s+\b(\w+)\b){5})/  would 'normally' work, but because of the ' in "can't" it will not match. ( see regex101.com )

try this   ((\s+\b([[:word:]]+)\b)){5}   (works in regex101.com )

@StephenP, it doesn't have to be exact 5 words, since there are alternative quantifier expressions such as {min,} or {min,max}. For the sake of this example I am trying to get exactly 5 words. On the pattern comment, I'm aware that the quantifier is trying to match the previous token which in my case is \b(word boundry which is zero-width).

@ticktalk, i tried your last regex and didn't work.

@Vivek - "it doesn't have to be exact 5 words" ... I get that. My point, though, is that you have to specify something as the way that you can determine when/where to stop matching. I understand that it is not "5 words". But giving this one specific example, you haven't specified the general rule to follow to determine the condition to stop matching. For example, if every error message specified a "because" reason you could stop matching when you found "because". (I doubt that is the case, it's just an example of an end condition)

@StephenP, thanks for clarifying, the general rule here is: 5 words after the first presence of \s-\s

To match words that may include apostrophes, instead of \w+ use [\w']+.
This matches "We can't save this record:" from the sample input:
(?<=- )(?:[\w':]+ ??){5}

See live demo.
Note the use of the reluctant optional quantifier ?? not match the space after the last word.
Since the entire match is your target, if you need to refer to it, for example in a replacement expression, rather that naming it in a group, use group 0 (which means "the whole match").

the final regex expression which i ended up using is (?<error_type>(?<=- )(?:[\w':]+.??){5}), which is based of your answer. Since I didn't need to capture anything, I used a non-capture group (?:) and stored the final result in a named group (?<error_type>). If you edit your answer with the new regex, I can mark it as accepted.

The captured group can be ignored; the entire match is what you want (but I've added non-capture, even though IMHO it makes the regex less readable). Although your example didn't show : I've added that too - please edit your question to include the colon, otherwise, readers will be confused as to why it's in the regex. As for grouping and naming the entire match, that's unnecessary - just refer to group zero for that - so I've left that out so the answer is more widely usable by future visitors.

could you please edit your answer to include : in We can't save this record:

@Vivek done. And demo link updated too.

python (3.9.5) test
cat vivek.py 
import re
input="""OBJ: redacted - We can't save this record because the “FBE Record-Trigger: redacted After Save"""
print( "Sample string:[" + input + "]" )

res=re.search("- ((\w+.)){6}", input )

print( input[res.start():res.end()] )

#
# run the test
#
python3 vivek.py 
Sample string:[OBJ: redacted - We can't save this record because the “FBE Record-Trigger: redacted After Save]
- We can't save this record 

hopefully this is of some help ...

If you (according to the comments under the answer of Bohemian) use this character class [\w:'] to match a word in your context, and you are using pcre, you can start the match with -  and then use \K to forget that match followed by matching the 5 words.
- \K[\w:']+(?: [\w:']+){4}

The pattern matches:

-  Match literally
\K Forget what is matched so far
[\w:']+ Match 1 or more occurrences of a word char, : or '
(?: [\w:']+){4} Repeat 4 times a space and 1+ times the same allowed characters

See a regex demo.

If there should be at least a single word character present per word, and preventing a partial word match in the last occurrence with a whitespace boundary (?!\S) at the end:
-\s+\K[:']*\w[\w:']*(?:\s+[:']*\w[\w:']*){4}(?!\S)

See another regex demo.

I like the \K. But, got wrangled in the first word match following the repeat match. I tried to remove the first [\w:'] pattern before the repeat match, which then does not match anything.

@Vivek Can you give an example string that you wanted to match?

@Vivek The answer that you accepted also matches We can't in the string - We can't  which is not 5 words, is that correct?

Thanks for pointing that out that the accepted answer does not always match exactly 5 words. There are situations when the text ends and no further characters are present in which case also should match after the presence of -. So for example:  OBJ: redacted - We can't, can match We can't

@Vivek But then I think you can write it as - \K[\w:']+(?: [\w:']+){0,4} https://regex101.com/r/0shHEV/1
